# how do i install custom c++ libraries?

Tags: c, eclipse

i'm taking a computer security class and i was hoping i can get some pointers on how to install custom libraries the professor had uploaded. the main language is C which i am not very familiar with. i am using eclipse for c/c++.

if eclipse is not a great choice for c please direct me to the best program for c.
installing these libraries in my laptop is not required because its already installed in the labs in school but i'd prefer it if i could do thing on my own laptop.

thanks!

ps: reason i like eclipse is because of the alignment command it has =/

using window 7 64bit...

http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~fazio/F11-csc48000/lab0/install-libs.html

here is my prof's website for the lab...

Comment: You might want to edit the title and tags to clarify that you're using Eclipse, because the answer will be very different in different IDEs.

Comment: In addition to the above, what OS are you using? What do the libraries come with? (i.e. only a .so or .dll or install package) What did you try that did not work already? (also I think this is more a question for Super User)

Comment: updated... using eclipses with window 7

Comment: The link is very Unix-centric (using `gmake`, `configure`, etc.), which are not normal tools available on Windows. You will have to build the code first, and without straying too far from the path, you might want to look into installing Cygwin, which will give you a comparable environment to at least build the code the site talks about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download a free copy of Virtual Box.
2. Install the same linux distro that your class uses in it.
3. Run eclipse in there, and just do what your professor tells you to for those libraries.

Any attempt to do this on native Windows will cost you more time that you can possibly afford.

Comment: i have ubuntu on my virtual machine, should i use that?

Comment: Considering the Unix-centric nature of these libraries, this solution is indeed probably the best. Alternatively, try to get a Unix account on a computer somewhere (at your university or elsewhere), or use cygwin.

Comment: thanks! turns out the prof wants us to do the projects in the school linux lab where everything is set up =/...